# How to generate models by OpenAPI without keeping the component object

Tags: axios, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm building a small React application with the use of Axios and OpenAPI. I plan to use Axios for HTTP requests and all I want from the openapi-typescript generator is to generate models for me which I can later use for my Node.js backend as well, not just on the FE.

The problem I encountered is that if I simply create schemas without defining paths, like so:

```
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      $ref: ./objects/user.yaml
    Address:
      type: object
      properties:
        street:
          type: string
        city:
          type: string
        country:
          type: string
```

..the generator generates the following structure for me:

```
export interface components {
    schemas: {
        User: components["schemas"]["user"];
        Address: {
            street?: string;
            city?: string;
            country?: string;
        };
        Hobbies: string[];
```

Is there any way I can get rid of the components and schemas objects and directly export every type (like User, Address) so that I can easily use them in my code?

Thanks for any input in advance.